# How to compare string with another string using c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a situation where i don't want to compare  total string length to other string .

Example:

```
string MainString = "Deanna Ecker";

string SearchString = "Ecker Designs";

int value = MainString.IndexOf(SearchString);
```

here it is searching with whole string. but i need to find any **word** in MainString. not with whole string..

Let me know how is this possible.

Comment: Split string by space and then search by each part of splitted string

Comment: given answers solve your problem. if you are also interested in matching words like "apple" with "apples" or "aple", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 8):

If case-sensitivity is not an issue, you could split both strings by the space, then intersect the two lists to see if there are any matches:

```
var foundWords = MainString.Split(' ').Intersect(SearchString.Split(' '));
```

Or if you only want to know if a word was found:

```
var isMatch = MainString.Split(' ').Intersect(SearchString.Split(' ')).Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your string to a char array then search each character via looping from all characters
such that

```
public bool MatchString(string first,string second)
{
  char[] ch1=first.ToCharArray();
  char[] ch2=second.ToCharArray();
  bool match=false;
  for(int i=0 ; i<ch1.length ; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0 ; j<ch2.length ; j++)
       {
             if(ch2[j]==ch[i])
              {
                match=true;
                break;
              } 
       }
   }
 return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `var wordMatch = MainString.Split(' ').Intersect(SearchString.Split(' ')).Any();`